# Como girar una imagen con earth engine conpython?

Tags: python

Tengo una `colletion` de imágenes y deseo poder rotar y reflectar las misma, tengo hasta el momento el siguiente código:

```py
bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7']
l7sr = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')

def cloudMaskL457(image):
    qa = image.select('pixel_qa')
    cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5).And(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7)).Or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3))
    mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min())
    return image.updateMask(cloud.Not()).updateMask(mask2).select(bands).divide(10000)

image = l7sr.filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31').map(cloudMaskL457).median()
```

Answer (score 0):

para rotar hay una forma más simple con la librería PIL:

```html
from PIL import Image
imagen_rotada     = imagen_sinrotar.rotate(45) #rotar la imagen
imagen_reflectada = ImageOps.mirror(imagen_rotada) #espejo de la imagen
new_image.save("imagen_rotada_reflectada.jpg")
```